# Recreating image from Y Cb Cr numpy arrays Python

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, numpy-ndarray

I have 3 numpy arrays with Y, Cb and Cr. I was able to show them individually and now I want to merge them and show the result Image.
I tried this:

```
Y, Cb, Cr = somefunction() //returns 3 numpy.ndarrays

print(Y.shape)  //(160, 160)
print(Y.dtype)  //float64
print(Cb.shape) //(160,160)
print(Cb.dtype) //float32
print(Cr.shape) //(160,160)
print(Cr.dtype) // float32

img_Y = im.fromarray(Y, mode=None)
img_Cb = im.fromarray(Cb, mode=None)
img_Cr = im.fromarray(Cr, mode=None)

im.merge('YCbCr', (img_Y, img_Cb, img_Cr))
```

but I get this error:

```
    im.merge('YCbCr', (img_Y, img_Cb, img_Cr))
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2957, in merge
    raise ValueError("mode mismatch")
ValueError: mode mismatch
```

Comment: Please show `Y.shape`, likewise `Cb.shape` and `Cr.shape`. And also their `dtype`. Thank you.

Comment: I justed added it, thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34913005/color-space-mapping-ycbcr-to-rgb

Comment: Unfortunately no, I want to display them directy with the 3 components Y Cb Cr, is this possible without converting to RGB ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot merge a `float64` Y-channel with `float32` Cb/Cr-channels, and PIL doesn't support any [colourspaces](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/concepts.html#concept-modes) (modes) with more than a one 32-bit float channel.

So, you will need to scale your values to the range 0..255 and convert to `uint8`, as per the link above, in order to go to a `YCbCr` colourspace.

Comment: Done ! Sorry I can't up vote it yet I don't have enough reputation